# Hidden functions in cells

Tags: excel

I have an Excel form with some hidden functions. I'm not an Excel person so I'm translating it into another program code but I need help in understanding how Excel converts dates and time to make an arithmetic operations.
Here is an example:

```
 Cell B5: 11/9/12
 Function           
     =B5                =0.1/24           =D2+2415018.5+E2-$B$5/24
 D2: 11/9/12    E2: 0:06:00   F2: 2456240.96
```

So my problem is that I don't understand how Excel coverts D2 and E2 in the equation:
D2+2415018.5+E2-$B$5/24 so that I can write it in python code.

Would appreciate some clarification please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't follow your example, but what you need to know is that Excel stores dates as the number of days since January **0**, 1900 (not a typo). An hour is 1/24 of a day, a minute is 1/24/60, etc. See [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) for more.

Comment: +1 was about to type the same - `1.99999999` would equal `1.1.1900 23:59:59,999`

Comment: @A. Webb - Hi, I tried to calculate the number of days since 1900-1-1 and what Excel writes as the representation of 6/21/10 = 40350.0. In python I cannot represent 1900-1-0 so I added one day but still come up a with 40349. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Shejo284 What you are missing is February 29, 1900, a non-existent date since 1900 was not a leap year, which is a "feature" of Excel. This is described in the second paragraph under "Dates" of the article I linked to.

Comment: @A.Web Yes, you are right. I needed to add 2. Can I ask another question: in a cell E2 there is 12:00:00 and this is used in a arithmetic function E2*5.0. What is the value of E2 here? How do I convert 12:00:00? to a scalar?

Comment: @Shejo284 Each hour past midnight is 1/24 of the day, a day being 1. So noon would be 1/2 of the day or 0.5.